# Why do banks tend to decrease lending rates, when central banks cut rates?

Tags: interest-rates, central-banking, banking, interbank-rates

I am not clear of why banks could not leave lending rates unchanged following a rate cut from the central bank so to increase their interest rate margin and instead tend to lower their lending rates.

Comment: In simple terms, each bank is afraid they will lose market share to the competition if they don't react by cutting their rate.

Answer (score 1):

Why do gas stations decrease prices when oil prices drop?

Why do Dell/Hp/etc decrease their PC prices as component prices drop?

etc

etc

etc